# What are the ramifications of "Skipping .d.ts Checking" to improve typescript compile time?

Tags: typescript

I've been reading this [official article of typescript compiler performance](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Performance). At this time, it takes 6 seconds to compile my project and I'd like to reduce that by tackling some of the lowest hanging fruit.

[This section tells you how to get performance tracing information](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Performance#performance-tracing). I followed the steps and to my surprise, there's only one hotspot:

```bash
$ npx tsc --generateTrace trace_files
$ npx @typescript/analyze-trace trace_files/
Hot Spots
└─ Check file c:\<project>\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.dom.d.ts (786ms)

No duplicate packages found
```

My package.json file has a dev dependency on `"typescript": "^5.1.3"`, the latest version at this time. I'm assuming that `lib.dom.d.ts` comes from that. If I've already got the latest, is there anything I can do to reduce the time of this hotspot?

It seems like [this section is the answer to that question](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Performance#skipping-dts-checking) but there are parts of it I don't understand, and these parts sound very important. I have bolded them as followed:

> #### Skipping .d.ts Checking
>
> By default, TypeScript performs a full re-check of all `.d.ts` files
> in a project to find issues and inconsistencies; however, this is
> typically unnecessary. Most of the time, the `.d.ts` files are known
> to already work - **the way that types extend each other was already**
> **verified once, and declarations that matter will be checked anyway.<sup>1</sup>**
>
> TypeScript provides the option to skip type-checking of the `.d.ts`
> files that it ships with (e.g. `lib.d.ts`) using the
> `skipDefaultLibCheck` flag.
>
> Alternatively, you can also enable the `skipLibCheck` flag to skip
> checking *all* `.d.ts` files in a compilation.**<sup>2</sup>**
>
> **These two options can often hide misconfiguration and conflicts in
> `.d.ts` files<sup>3</sup>**, so we suggest using them *only* for faster builds.

1. They were already verified once? When? What does it mean by, "declarations that matter will be checked anyway?"
2. Hopefully the answer to #1 will clarify this but what are the ramifications of skipping all `.d.ts` files?
3. What kind of misconfigurations and conflicts can they hide? How do they happen? How will I know that these flags are the cause?

I'm not sure it's worth turning these flags on if they'll let errors slip through or if they'll report errors where none exist. Unfortunately, this documentation doesn't go into detail on the specifics, so I'd like some clarification.

Comment: If you don't want to check types, use `swc`, it's faster. If you just want to run, use `tsx` or `tsx watch`, it doesn't check types. If you want to check types continuously, use `tsc --watch`. If you want just to check types, take your time, 6s in CI is not a lot.